# Synching QField to my desktop QGIS project

Tags: qgis, qfield

I have created a project in QGIS on a desktop and transferred to a mobile device before digitising features using QField. How do I then synch the changes I have made on my mobile device back to my desktop QGIS project so that the new changes appear?

Comment: Did you use the QFieldSync plugin?

Comment: I did use the QField synch plugin. I copy everything back to my device in the same folder that my original desktop project was created in. I open the qfield file and the changes appear on my desktop. However when I open my QGIS desktop project and press the synchronise button under the QField sync plugin it displays the following error Synch dialog no .qgs project found in the following file destination.

Comment: If you are still working with QField you can try [QFieldCloud](https://qfield.cloud/) now.